# Exclude records present in a query

Tags: ms-access

I'm an Access novice trying to get a form to exclude all records present in a Find Duplicates Query. The duplicate query is identified by the variable ClassID, and the form is also identified by ClassID. I want to program the form so that any ClassIDs that show up in the Find Duplicates Query are excluded from my form. I've tried searching for other questions on this topic with no success. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to create a third query that selects all records from the first table that do not appear in the Find Duplicates Query.

`SELECT ID
FROM table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT
    ID, COUNT(*)
  FROM
    table1
  GROUP BY
    ID
  HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
)`

Substitute `table1` with the name of your table and `ID` with the field that would contain duplicate values.

Comment: Thanks! I should have mentioned that my form is based on another query rather than a table. I tried creating a query using the code you suggest, but I think I'm missing something. That code doesn't reference the Find Duplicates Query, so when I input it, I get the following error: You have written a subquery that can return more than one field without using the EXISTS reserved word in the main query's FROM clause. Revise the Select statement of the subquery to request only one field.

Comment: I apologize, use EXISTS instead of IN.  I've edited my response

Comment: I think I'm just being thick, but this still isn't working for me. It now just pops up all of the code after SELECT and says there's an error.

Comment: updated my answer, can't have the field name before NOT EXISTS

Comment: I reworked this a bit and got it to work! Thanks again for the assistance. My final code looked like this:

SELECT ID
FROM table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT ID
  FROM qryFindDuplicates
WHERE qryFindDuplicates.ID=table1.ID
)